# Локальное кэширование БД

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

При добавлении источника данных -базы, есть галочка включить локальное кэширование БД. Скажите что это и для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уже загуглил) кароче, наверное это мне не нужно у меня к базе буду подключаться не так уж часто ,так что наверное это я трогать не буду.
эшировать нужно данные, которые медленно генерируются и часто запрашиваются. На практике это обычно:

```
Результаты запросов к внешним сервисам (RSS, SOAP, REST и т.п.).
Результаты медленных выборок из базы данных.
Сгенерированные html блоки либо целые страницы.
```

[image: Кэширование SQL запроса]